# rsync not actually copying files

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to synchronize a large directory of files from my server to a local box. (Both are running Ubuntu.) I have a command that *looks* like it works, but certain files are not copied:

```
phrogz@planar:~$ cat ./sync-phrogz-public 
rsync -rztpl --stats --rsh=/usr/bin/ssh 69.46.18.236:/var/www/phrogz.net/public /var/www/phrogz.net/public

phrogz@planar:~$ ./sync-phrogz-public 
Number of files: 10320
Number of files transferred: 0
Total file size: 4221864770 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 197778
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 388
Total bytes received: 199213

sent 388 bytes  received 199213 bytes  79840.40 bytes/sec
total size is 4221864770  speedup is 21151.52

phrogz@planar:~$ la /var/www/phrogz.net/public/svg/convert*
-rw-r----- 1 phrogz www-admin 6404 2011-02-26 21:49 /var/www/phrogz.net/public/svg/convert_path_to_polygon.xhtml

phrogz@planar:~$ ssh 69.46.18.236 'ls -Fla /var/www/phrogz.net/public/svg/convert*'
-rw-r--r-- 1 phrogz phrogz 1951 2011-12-04 09:07 /var/www/phrogz.net/public/svg/convert_matrix.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 phrogz phrogz 6404 2011-02-26 21:49 /var/www/phrogz.net/public/svg/convert_path_to_polygon.xhtml
```

As you can see, the file `convert_matrix.html` did not get copied.

1. What is the command doing, if not actually copying files?
2. How do I get it to actually copy the files?

Comment: It is by chance present a local folder `/var/www/phrogz.net/public/public` ?

Comment: Whoa, yes, there is! Post that as an answer, and tell me how to change the command to not create `public` as a subfolder, and you've got yourself 25 rep :)

Comment: Remove the final "public" from your script, so it becomes: `rsync -rztpl --stats --rsh=/usr/bin/ssh 69.46.18.236:/var/www/phrogz.net/public /var/www/phrogz.net` - should do it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could simplify your command to

```
rsync -az --stats 69.46.18.236:/var/www/phrogz.net/public /var/www/phrogz.net/
```

or alternatively

```
rsync -az --stats 69.46.18.236:/var/www/phrogz.net/public/ /var/www/phrogz.net/public
```

As you see, `rsync` interprets differently a source with or without a trailing `/`.

Also, `-a` is equivalent to `-rtplogD`, (with respect to your command line, the `-a` also adds `-o`, preserve owner, `-g`, preserve group and `-D`, preserve devices and special files).

Finally, the `--rsh` option is redundant when the source or the destination is in the form `host:/path`, with a single `:`.